# Ethernet to NAS, Wifi to Internet on same subnet

Tags: wireless, ethernet, nas

On my Windows configuration, I use a Wifi to connect to the interwebs:

```
192.168.1.x (DHCP)
```

Also on my Windows configuration, I have a NAS and a second computer with Ubuntu connected via a switch on my ethernet port:

```
192.168.1.88 (NAS)
192.168.1.214 (Computer)
```

It is now possible to surf, but also to connect to the NAS via IP or name. Also I do have configured a bridge in Windows to allow the Ubuntu PC to connect to the Internet. This all works fine.

BUT if I use my Wifi Stick on the Ubuntu PC (to surf) and the ethernet switch to connect the Ubuntu PC to the NAS (same as Windows config), I can't ping or find the NAS.

I tried already to add a route

```
route add -host 192.168.1.88 dev eth0
```

but this didn't help.

Why is this? Where do I have to configure something or change properties to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, my NAS had somehow messed up the internal IP. I resetted the NAS, configured as shown above and now I can surf the interwebs over Wifi and use my NAS over Ethernet.